# (Puser Beams Notification) Serve/upload file from the root of my website

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, notifications, pusher, pusher-js

I'm building notification components for my ReactJS web app, and I'm using Pusher Beams, I don't understand step 2 in this tutorial, can anyone explain how to "serve this file from the root of your website"?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, it means putting the service-worker.js file in public folder(I'm using React, so here it's public folder)